# Get string from to odoo 9

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, odoo

How get string from first character in my example letter 'T' to first slash '/'

TEST/0001      need get TEST

TEST2/0001     need get TEST2

TEST3/0001     need get TEST3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, you can use [split() function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) which returns array of elements splitted by the character you specify. Then you get the first element:

```
yourString = "TEST/0001"

yourString.split("/")[0]

>>> 'TEST'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the `split` solution, but in case you are looking for a more complete and at the same time simple solution (assuming you know regexes, which anyway should belong to any programmer's knowledge) then you can use a few shortcut methods from the standard-library [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re).

An example with your same data would be:

```
import re

lines = ["TEST/1000", "TEST2/1000", "TEST3/1000"]
pattern = "TEST\d*(?=/)"    # Take any string beginning with TEST, followed by 0 or more digits and a / character

for line in lines:
    match = re.match(pattern, line)

    if match is not None:
        print(match.group(0))    # match.group(0) returns the whole matched string, and not a part of it
    else:
        print("No match for %s" % line)
```

With my setup, running this script inside a `test.py` file yields:

```
None@vacuum:~$ python3.6 ./test.py 
TEST
TEST2
TEST3
```